# signing email with digital certificate from another email account same domain thunderbird

Tags: email, certificate, public-key-encryption, thunderbird

I created a digital certificate for an email address with the purpose of being able to sign emails, encrypt emails etc from that specific address.

But I use thunderbird with enigmail add-on. And in thunderbird, I also have another email account, same domain, but its my wife email.

I realized that my wife email address is now also capable of digitally signing and encrypt emails using the digital certificate I created for my email.

Is this ok? I mean, I though thunderbird would only allow me to sign a message if such specific sender email had its own digital certificate, and not using the digital certificate of another email address even if from same domain.

Or maybe something is not configured as it should?

Hope I was clear.

Thanks in advance for any clarification I tried to find an answer but could not find anything so im really confused.